# Dynamic Stretches for Couch to 5K

Tags: couchto5k

This morning I came across website that demonstrated dynamic stretches, it swing leg side to side, pike stretch, walking lunge, etc.

Snow I cannot find the link to this website. It actually included video if lady demonstrating these exercises. I believe it is from active.com

Well I just tried the dynamic stretches I remember and my hips feel million times better (I had mild tightness for 2 weeks but thought it would go away on its own)

1. Please recommend more dynamic stretches that improve hip mobility. That will open up the hips.
2. Also recommend other dynamic exercise for running, esp for couch to 5K.

Thank you kindly

Comment: If the below answer helped please accept it as an answer, if not please feel free to ask more questions

Comment: @MuntasirAlam Can you answer this question, http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/32341/when-to-begin-couch-to-5k-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be considered a stretch ,or may not be, but most lifters generally use this machine called the hip abduction. You can find on how to use this machine on youtube.

[image]

If you have no access to a gym (get a membership!) you can try the exercise in the picture below. This will work as the same effect, but make sure you are pausing at the highest point of the abduction. If you are new to this you probably can't raise your legs too high.

[image]

Here is an actual exercise, but I recommend to do it with no weight at all so it actually becomes a dynamic stretch really.

The important thing here is that you have to go ALL the way down, and when you come up, push your hips out during the squat. This is probably hands down the best way to improve hip mobility. At first you want be able to squat all the way down that low, but trust me if you practice you will be extremely flexible and the squat transfers well into running sports.

[image]

[image]

This is a static stretch

Heres another good hip movement which is great for flexibility. I'm actually not too sure what this is exactly called, but I and several other athletes generally do this at the end of the workout ( this is a static stretch)

Comment: To improve your final picture, id suggest this post and associated video: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/54fphc/the_hip_flexors_are_the_muscles_near_the_front_of/?