# When to begin Couch to 5K Program

Tags: stretching, couchto5k

When to begin Couch to 5K Program.

I can do 108 [Surya Namaskar](http://www.artofliving.org/surya-namaskar-sun-salutation12-poses-leaner-you) in one sitting (takes an hour). And I can stationary bike 15 minutes at a time.

However, I have left tight hip for past 2+ weeks. I feel the discomfort when performing [donkey kicks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJ1Xuz9D-ZQ)

I was told to perform dynamic stretching for relief.

Should I wait till hips are better, or can I gradually start couch to 5K now? Is there other stretches/exercises I can do to prepare for couch to 5K? Thank you.

Comment: When you say discomfort do you feel pain or is it more of  a "sore" feeling? If it is the latter start as soon as possible. Believe it or not, the best way to get rid of tightness and soreness is just to do more of that specific movement.

Comment: @MuntasirAlam No pain, more of discomfort. I don't know about sore though. I don't think it's sore, just discomfort. This morning it felt fine but after 108 Surya Namaskars the tightness was there again. Whenever I get the chance, I do dynamic stretch.

Answer (score 2):

If you are feeling discomfort in any part of the body, the best thing to do is not to strain it any further. I'd say get yourself checked. The problem may be minor, but if not given proper attention, it may aggravate in time. Yes, wait till you feel completely fine. Your goal is to gain fitness and reach your target without pain. So, get the root cause of the discomfort and get rid of it.

Comment: Will have to do dynamic and static stretches. Perhaps heating pad would work. I really wish to start this wonderful program!

Comment: I wish you the very best.

Answer (score 2):

Playing devils advocate here:

See your doctor if the pain...

- Started in the middle of your workout
- Is sharp and localized
- The pain persists for longer than 4 days.

Otherwise, if it is a dull ache and you **can** still run then you should feel/be able to.

Comment: Its a dull ache that's been there for 2+ weeks. Only time I feel tightness is when I do donkey kicks. Dynamic stretches and heating pad are helping. Otherwise I can do 108 Surya Namaskar, 15 min stationary bike, 10 to 15 lb weights easily.